# General Units question

Tags: mathematics, unit

so let’s say I worked out a quantity that turned out to be unit less but to work it out I used pounds (lb) and feet (ft) and the units cancelled out

But then I used this unit less number later in another formula, but then I used kg and m, is this correct to do please?

I tried it, and I got the same answer both ways?

Comment: I would be deeply suspicious.  Either that shouldn't resolve, or it's something like length/length and you missed that simplification.  Did you use "lb" for both pound-force and pound-mass, and did you use "kg" for both kilograms and 9.81 Newtons (i.e., the force exerted by a 1kg mass in one earth gravity)?  Perhaps show what you actually did.

Comment: Hi, so I found number ‘x’ using lb just (the lb cancelled out) and then number ‘x2’ using kg (2 different formula)

Comment: If you want an answer, give us a question that's specific enough.  Please _edit your question_ to give the _exact formulae_ that you used to get your $x$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Tip: it's "unitless". ***-less***,
an adjective suffix meaning “without” (childless; peerless), and in adjectives derived from verbs, indicating failure or inability to perform or be performed (resistless; tireless). When you use "less" on it's own it implies subtraction as in "house less its windows" (which would be a windowless house).

Answer (score 0):

Pounds and kilograms are not necessarily interchangeable in a formula.

Pounds is not mass, you have to turn it into slugs to get mass.  A Pound is a force.

Comment: 1-lbm (pound-mass) under the influence of 1-g (force of standard gravity) produces 1-lbf (pound-force).

Answer (score 0):

A true unitless quantity is independent of the units used to derive it.

However, you must be sure that the quantity you've found is actually unitless.

From what I've understood of your question, you calculated the quantity by effectively calculating a ratio where the numerator and denominator both use weight and length values, in such a way that the units can be properly extracted and cancel out: $\dfrac{f(\text{weight, length})_1}{f(\text{weight, length})_2}$.

As long as you did the work correctly, the quantity will indeed be dimensionless and can be used with any other units of weight (not mass!) and length.